How to get the shared URL of a file from Google Drive in Google Colab
I am working on Google Colab.
Say I mounted Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/')
f = open ('myfile.txt')
f.write ('Hello')
f.close () # How can I get the share URL of myfile.txt here?

Then I write a file to a directory to Google Colab using Python. Is it possible to have the URL of this file after writing?
Many thanks

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
